# resharper8 cannot find vs2012 on installation

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm installing resharper 8 (the latest till now) onto vs2012, but when I ran the .msi file, it says "unsatisfied requirement: microsoft visualstudio" which means resharper cannot detect any visual studio installed on on PC. But I do have VS 2012 ultimate version installed and registered.

Can anyone give me help?

My vs2012 has also update3 installed. I'm now trying update4.

Thanks in advance.

Leo

Answer (score 0):

After having the same problem I looked more into it reading the system requirements - I didn't realize it doesn't work with Visual studio Express versions, I'm guessing that's the problem you're having.

Source:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/system_requirements.html